# Creating an mouse-friendly GUI in a "sort of" Python console mode

Tags: python

I'm developing a real-time [rogue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_%28video_game%29)-like game during my spare time, using Python and [libtcod](http://doryen.eptalys.net/libtcod/), to learn programming (and have some fun). I would like to create some sort of mouse-friendly GUI, just like in [Goblin Camp](http://www.goblincamp.com/).

This game is 90% mouse-driven, with menus, scrollbars, buttons etc.
As a total noob with graphical interfaces, I just can't figure out how to do this. Example: How to display the name of a monster when the cursor is over it? I tried some ways, which more or less worked, but were always awful, impossible to maintain, hard to scale, and resource-consuming.

Is there a "simple" way to have something more like an object.OnClick() ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question, but your english is quite good.  I've seen much worse (sometimes from native speakers!)

Comment: Is the problem related to the fact that you have to display text in a limited space? Or is a problem of how to organize the software so you can code entities that can react to mouse events in general?

Comment: Organization problem. When I click on that (ascii) mob, or that button, I don't want to cycle through all objects to figure out which one is under my mouse. I want the object to tell me "you clicked on me!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply need to do an Object.onSomething() probably you need to write a reactor over a object data model.

What I mean? Put every relevant objects into a container make this container available to everyone. This container will implement the method

```
def castEvent(self, eventName, args, kargs):
```

In this method you iterate the containing object looking for the method "does%s" % eventName.
something like:

```
for item in self.items:
    f = getattr(item, "does%s" % eventName, lambda *x, **k : False)
```

if f evaluates True using the parameters passed to the function then you call the "do%s"%eventName with the same parameters:

```
for item in self.items:
    f = getattr(item, "does%s" % eventName, lambda *x, **k : False)
    if f(*args, **kargs):
        f = getattr(item, "do%s" % eventName, lambda *x, **k : False)
        f(*args, **kargs)
```

Every time you need to send an event - say *Click* - you simply need to:

```
container.castEvent("Click",[],{"x":10,"y":20})
```

every object interested in Clicks has to provide a

```
def doesClick(self, x, y):
```

that manage the click events returning False or

```
def doesClick(self, x, y):
[...]
def doClick(self, x, y):
```

The first returning whether (x,y) hits the object and the second doing the click routine.

You can implement the first in a generic superclass and let the clickable classes to extend.

This is a very basic implementation whit a lot of room for improvements.

Comment: Thank you! That wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but its a really better written system than the one I tried. I guess I've still a lot to learn in Python...

Comment: @simcamb have you troubles with the integrationton?

Comment: @Fxll I'm working on it right now, I understand how it works, but I don't get the use of lambda (I only know it works like a "one line function") in *args.

Comment: If a method does not exist for item, getattr(item,"method",x) returns x. In this case x is a function with a generic signature that returns false.

Comment: @Fxll Right, that was obvious. I didn't read it right, thanks again.